# Inject additional stylesheets (or scripts) in Facelets template client

Tags: jsf-2

I have the following master template file for my JSF based pages :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
   <title><ui:insert name="title">MyApp</ui:insert></title>
   <h:outputStylesheet name="stylesheet.css" library="styles"/>
</h:head>

<h:body>

   <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
         <ui:insert name="header">
            // header content
         </ui:insert>
      </div>

      <div id="content">
         <ui:insert name="content">
         </ui:insert>
      </div>

      <div id="footer">
         <ui:insert name="footer">
         </ui:insert>
      </div>
   </div>
</h:body>

</html>
```

In the head section, we have `stylesheet.css`. This stylesheet contains all my global styles which are common to all pages.

In the template client, I would like to add page specific stylesheet. So, I tried adding the following line in my template client page:

```
<ui:composition template="/pages/templates/template.xhtml">
   <ui:define name="content">
      <h:outputStylesheet name="indexPage.css" library="styles" target="head"/>

      // body content

</ui:composition>
```

This, however, does not seem to add `indexPage.css` in the generated HTML's head section.

I am using Mojarra 2.1.2. Does it support the `target` attribute? I don't see it listed as one of the available in my autosuggest options in Eclipse.

In case it doesn't, how do I inject the *additional* page specific CSS while still using templates?

Comment: Works fine for me. The output stylesheet can't be retargeted elsewhere (as that's not valid HTML). It will always end up in HTML head. So `target` attribute is in fact superfluous in output stylesheet. The output script can be retargeted (either head, or inline, or end of body).

Comment: Please doublecheck your actual code. This construct will fail the way as you described (i.e. it does not end up as `<link>` anywhere in the HTML `<head>`) when the `<h:outputStylesheet>` is not enclosed inside a valid `<ui:define>`.

Answer (score 10):

Add to your master template file inside `head` section new template content specially for **css** files linking:

```
<h:head>
   <title><ui:insert name="title">MyApp</ui:insert></title>
   <h:outputStylesheet name="stylesheet.css" library="styles"/>
   <ui:insert name="css"/>
</h:head>
```

In template client page add page specific stylesheet like this:

```
<ui:composition template="/pages/templates/template.xhtml">
   <ui:define name="css">
      <h:outputStylesheet name="indexPage.css" library="styles"/>
   </ui:define>
   ...
</ui:composition>
```

Instead of `h:outputStylesheet` coud be used `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="relative path to css file">`.
Important that `ui:insert` for **css** in master template should be inside `h:head`.

Comment: Note that this is basically what `target="head"` already does.

Comment: tag [**h:outputStylesheet**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) does not have attribute **target** in jsf 2.1 (nor it works even though specified)

Comment: It's the fixed default already. See also 1st comment on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similiar problem and a friend helped me.
The solution was to import the css in a subheader of a ui:composition

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    template="/template.xhtml"
>
    <ui:define name="subheader">
        <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="my-style.css" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
    </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```